# Exporting individual mySQL records to individual PDF files

Tags: mysql, pdf-generation, export, records

We are collecting responses from users in a comment form. In addition to saving these records in our mySQL database, we need to export individual records as PDF files formatted as a reasonable facsimile to the original comment form, i.e.

Name: John Smith. 
Address: 123 Main St. 
Comment: I like this form. 
What is your favorite color? Red.

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: How are the records retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Well you should probably use a serverside language for your logic.  I would loop through the records you want in php and then create pdf's with php.  Here's a good link to get your started:

http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Create-Pdf-Php_t4972.html